# TypeError: chat.insertOne is not a function at POST

Tags: node.js, next.js

I am working on a chat system where users can send messages to each other i tried using mongodb and nextjs to implement this but im running into some error along the way

Below is my code

```
import { connectDB } from '@/app/lib/database';
import Chat from '@/app/models/chat';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function POST(req) {
    const { postOwner, userId, username, message, senderId } = await req.json();
    await connectDB();

    const chat = await Chat.findOne({ members: { $all: [postOwner, userId] } });

    if (!chat) {
        chat.create(
            { members: [userId, postOwner] },
            { chat: [{ username, message, senderId }] }
        );
        console.log(chat);
        return NextResponse.json(
            { message: 'Chat Created', chat },
            { status: 200 }
        );
    } else {
        console.log(chat);
        chat.insertOne({ chat: [{ username, message, senderId }] });

        return NextResponse.json(
            { message: 'Chat added', chat },
            { status: 200 }
        );
    }
}
```

This is the model I'm using

```
import mongoose, { Schema, models } from 'mongoose';

const chatSchema = new Schema(
    {
        members: {
            userId: String,
            postOwner: String,
        },
        chat: {
            username: String,
            message: String,
            senderId: String,
        },
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);

const Chat = models.Chat || mongoose.model('Chat', chatSchema);
export default Chat;
```

This is the error message i am geting

> TypeError: chat.insertOne is not a function
> at POST (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/api/chat/route.js:46:14)